# IIS URL rewrite issue with web.config

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

i had a .htaccess rewrite using mod_rewrite and i used an online convertor to convert it to IIS's web.config.

Here is one line in my web.config:

```
 <rule name="rule 1G">
    <match url="cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$ index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  />
 </rule>
```

With that i get error:

```
Configuration file is not well-formed XML
```

That error is getting triggered in the second line above.

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Below is part of the original htaccess file:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

## Activate the mod_rewrite Engine

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$    index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape ampersands in attribute values with `&amp;`:

```
<rule name="rule 1G">
  <match url="cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$ index.php?_a=viewCat&amp;catId=$1&amp;%1"  ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  />
</rule>
```

NB. You may find http://xmlvalidation.com/ helpful for debugging XML files.

**UPDATE**

The change above will only fix XML validity error but not the rewrite rule itself. The `match` element should only describe the match condition (i.e. the first part of your Apache RewriteRule) while the target URL should be described in the `action` element.

The backreferences also have different syntax.

I'd suggest trying the following rule definition (unfortunately I can't check myself for the lack of IIS on hand):

```
<rule name="rule 1G">
  <match url="cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?_a=viewCat&amp;catId={R:1}&amp;" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Have you fixed both ampersands in your url="..."? There are two of them. Did you try the online XML validation tool against your changed file? It will point out the exact position of an error.